# Непонятная логическая ошибка

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Написал программу, которая при вводе цифры в виде названия выдаст саму цифру, и наоборот. К примеру, при вводе `"one"` программа выводит `"1"`, при вводе `"1"` она выдает `"one"`, и т.д. до девяти.

```
int main()
{

    vector<string> numb = {"zero", "one", "two", 
    "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};

    vector<int> val = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}; 


   for (string num; cin >> num;)
{
   bool found = false;
   int b  = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < numb.size(); ++i)
  {
       if (num == numb[i])
       {
           found = true;
           b = i;
           break;
       }
  }
       if (found)
            cout << val[b] << endl;

        else
     for (int a = 0; cin >> a;)
    {
        cout << numb[a] << endl;
        break;
    }


}
    return 0;
}
```

И с буквенным вводом и численным выводом все в порядке, а вот с вводом числа и выводом "букв" работает через раз. Т.е я ввожу `"1"` и ничего не происходит - ни ошибки, ни чего-то иного. Затем я еще раз ввожу `"1"`, и тогда программа выдает `"one"`. Помогите понять, что не так, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы уже прочли число, оно не совпало со строками. И вы **опять** пытаетесь его читать...

Замените блок `else` на приведенный:

```
    else
    {
        int a = stoi(num);
        cout << numb[a] << endl;
    }
```

И учтите, что у вас совершенно не обрабатываются ошибки! Что, если я введу `"один"` или 845? Подумайте над этим...

Comment: Благодарю. Да, над ошибками пока не думал, ибо заставить хотя бы так работать :D
И не могли бы вы поподробнее разъяснить, за чем мне писать строку int a = stoi(num); ?

Comment: Потому что `num` у вас **строка**, а вам нужно **число**.